# How to set prepare statement correctly in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I set following sql, and execute them. Those SQL was correctly readed and stored to `@myquery`

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT id ",
",coalesce( sum( IF( snapshot_day = date(now() - INTERVAL 3 DAY), 1 ,0) )) AS '",date(now() - INTERVAL 3 DAY),"' ",
",coalesce( sum( IF( snapshot_day = date(now() - INTERVAL 2 DAY), 1 ,0) )) AS '",date(now() - INTERVAL 2 DAY),"' ",
",coalesce( sum( IF( snapshot_day = date(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1 ,0) )) AS '",date(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY),"' ",
"FROM table",
"WHERE type in ('Daily') ",
"GROUP BY 1") INTO @myquery;

SELECT @myquery;

PREPARE stmt FROM @myquery;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But when `PREPARE` statement , the following error returned.

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in ('Daily') GROUP BY 1' at line 1`

What is the wrong point of this query ? is this depend on its server version ?

it seems there is no problems.

If some one has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Show the output of `SELECT @myquery;`

Comment: `date(now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` == `CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no space between the table name and the WHERE keyword:

```
"FROM table",
"WHERE type in ('Daily') ",
```

So after the fragments are concatenated together, your query will become:

```
... FROM tableWHERE type in ('Daily') ...
```

MySQL will think you have a table named `tableWHERE`, which may be okay at least for the sake of syntax. It hasn't yet checked to see if this table exists.

Then you are giving it a table alias `type`, which is still okay syntactically.

But then the table alias is followed by `in` which confused MySQL. That's not the right place for an `in` predicate.

You can fix this in the following way:

```
"FROM table ",
"WHERE type in ('Daily') ",
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes with `CONCAT`, and then escape the single quotes for the string literal inside the `IN` clause.  Also, you should just give literal names for the aliases.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT id',
    ', COALESCE(SUM(IF(snapshot_day = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY), 1, 0))) AS now_minus_3',
    ', COALESCE(SUM(IF(snapshot_day = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY), 1, 0))) AS now_minus_2',
    ', COALESCE(SUM(IF(snapshot_day = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0))) AS now_minus_1 ',
    'FROM table ',
    'WHERE type in (''Daily'') ',
    'GROUP BY 1') INTO @myquery;
```